# How do I design a database for Shopping Cart

Tags: c#

I want to design a product website using MVC & Entity Framework.

Currently I have 2 product type for products

1. Products will will be sold as per weight
2. products which will be sold in boxes

I created the following classes:

```
public class Products
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public int ProductCatagoryID { get; set; }
}

public class DryFruits : Products
{
    public decimal WeightInGrams { get; set; }
    public decimal RatePerGram { get; set; }
}

public class DryFruitsPacks : Products
{
    public string PackName {  get; set;  }
    public decimal PackSize { get; set; }
    public decimal RatePerGram { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to create the database, I am confused do I need to create 3 tables?

Please help

Comment: Yes, for this design I would use three tables. Although you could move RatePerGram to products. Typically you can use an ORM such as NHibernate to design it's own schema based on your class structure

Answer (score 1):

First thing first.you should design proper Database table before come-up with coding.according to your scenario you can go for three option. the selection is up-to you.

you can come up with three tables as below

```
Products{ProductId,ProductName, ProductCatagoryID}
DryFruits{Id,ProductId,RatePerGram}
DryFruitsPacks{Id,PackName,PackSize, RatePerGram}
```

or else you can achieve that using two tables as below

```
DryFruits{ProductId,ProductName,ProductCatagoryID,WeightInGrams,RatePerGram}
DryFruitsPacks{ProductId,ProductName,ProductCatagoryID,PackName,PackSize,RatePerGram}
```

or else you can do it by having a single table as below

```
Products{ProductId,ProductName, ProductCatagoryID,Id,ProductId,RatePerGram,Id,PackName,PackSize, RatePerGram}
```